# .htaccess - Redirect to a subfolder according to the preferred language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

we have a website in English. Now we want to have a translated copy of this website in German.

The index.html is located in the root folder: www.mydomain.com/index.html

Now I want to create a htaccess file which redirects all user which have set the preferred language in their browser to German (de, de-de, de-at, de-ch) to www.mydomain.com/de/index.html. All other user should be redirected to www.mydomain.com/en/index.html.

I tried a lot but I can't make it work. I do not really understand the regular expression thing and it's usage.
Most of the tries ended up with error 403 or 500. The current htaccess doesn't end up in an error, but it doesn't work.

The htaccess is now:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /de/$1 [L] 

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

It seems like the file doesn't work at all. When I open www.mydomain.com it opens www.mydomain.com/index.html

Htaccess and rewriting works in general:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com/ [R=301,L]
```

works.

If I delete the slash behind ^

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

I get an error 500.

What do I do wrong?

I actually want the server to redirect to the webpage which the user tried to open. So if the user opens mydomain.com/index2.html he should be redirected to mydomain.com/xx/index2.html (and not to index.html)

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jaroslaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|de)/ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1 [L] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

Comment: How can you type so fast? :) Now I get a blank page.

Comment: try updated code and also test this in Firebug to see what http status you're getting.

Comment: The same problem. Firebugs says 200 OK and a blank html document is displayed.